# Creating virtualbox desktop shortcut in as Separate / Detachable

Tags: virtualbox, desktop, shortcut

Good day. Creating desktop shortcut of headless mode vmachine is easy. But I am wondering how to create a desktop shortcut of detachable/separate mode vmachine? It seems /usr/lib/virtualbox/virtualbox --startvm "VM name" --type "separate" or /usr/lib/virtualbox/vboxmanage --startvm "VM name" --type "separate" are not working at all.

anyone can help?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution.  Modify the shortcut command to this:

`/usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxmanage startvm "UUID or name" --type separate`